# How do I find the basis for a subspace of functions?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let V = C[0,1] and let W be a subspace spanned by the set {f(t), g(t), h(t), k(t)} where

f(t) = e^-t , g(t) = e^t , h(t) = cosh(t) , k(t) = 2(e^-t + 3e^t)

And I want to find the basis for W. I can see that k(t) is a linear combination of f(t) and g(t), but am unsure of where to go from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\cosh t=\frac{e^t+e^{-t}}2$$
So $h$ is a linear combination of $f$ and $g$ as well, and a basis for $W$ is just $\{f,g\}$.

Comment: thanks, I forgot what cosh was!